# PHP: Getting first character of the first word and three characters of the second

Tags: php

I am trying to create unique email addresses based on the first name and last name of a person.

For example, I would like to create an email address like

t.smi@domain.com from the name Thomas Smith

or

w.bil@domain.com for William Billed

So basically the first name should return 1 character and I want to take three characters from the family name.

I tried to find a solution but it seems like people try similar things but not exactly what I am looking for.

I managed to get something like

`$thename = "Peter Bonds";
$pos = stripos($thename, ' ');
$themail = substr($thename, 0, $pos + 3);`

working to get the first name and two of the family name but failed badly to find a solution for my specific issue.

I would appreciate it greatly if someone could help out with a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `explode`, `strtolower` and `substr` functions:

```
$thename = "Peter Bonds";
$domain = "@domain.com";

$name_parts = explode(" ", $thename);
$theemail = strtolower($name_parts[0][0]. "." .substr($name_parts[1], 0, 3)). $domain;

print_r($theemail);
```

The output:

```
p.bon@domain.com
```

---

Another alternative could be the *one-line* solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$theemail = strtolower(preg_replace("/^(\w)\w+\s+(\w{3})\w*$/", "$1.$2". $domain, $thename));

print_r($theemail);   // p.bon@domain.com
```

Comment: I think the regular expression is the better of the two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You are just using the function wrong. Try this

```
<?php
  $thename = "Peter Bonds";
  $pos = stripos($thename, ' ');
  $themail = strtolower(substr($thename, 0, 1).'.'.substr($thename, $pos+1, 3).'@domain.com');
  echo $themail;
?>
```